# How to interactively simplify a formula in a relational theory in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I have a theory in Isabelle with relations but no functions (i.e., I have no terms besides variables) where I have first-order axioms about the relations.  I also have two formulas `P` and `Q` whose equivalence over the axioms I want to prove.  So far `sledgehammer` failed for me.  What I would like to do now is to have Isabelle generate simpler formulas equivalent to `P`, pick one `P'` of the simplified formulas that looks good, and derive a proof of the equivalence `Q` and `P'` by hand.

Can the interface of Isabelle to automated theorem provers used like this?  From what I've learned so far from Isabelle's manuals, I know how simplify formulas in some circumstances, but according to them I need to specify `P'` beforehand, and the the theory should contain equations.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "simpler". According to your axioms? Could you give more context?

Comment: @larsrh "According to your axioms?" Yes.